# Recover EFS Certificate from dead Motherboard

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, efs

I created an encrypted file with Windows 7 32-bit on a NAS (mybooklive) and backed the file (not the certificate) up locally to the computer's hard drive. The original Win7 computer had a motherboard failure.  I did not backup the EFS key before the board failed. The hard drive is in fine working condition, but the computer cannot boot.

1. Is there a way to recover the encrypted files without being forced to replace the motherboard on the dead machine?
2. If I re-image a different computer with a backed-up image of my Win7 hard drive, will those encrypted files become available? Will the new computer still work, or will the different drivers, etc cause a failure?
3. If I do replace the motherboard with a compatible but slightly different model (the original is not easily available), will I be able to recover the files just by booting the computer as normal?

Comment: Maybe a better question is simply how can I boot into this hard drive on a different laptop?  I expect boot failure due to different hardware, drivers, etc.  If I can boot into windows, I can export the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the hard drive out, and hook it up to a working computer with a usb -> ata/sata adapter.  You would then be able to extract the EFS keys.  You should be able to then use that key on a working windows installation to decrypt your backed-up files.