# How to use a hard drive containing EFS-encrypted files on another computer?

Tags: hard-drive, security, encryption, certificate, efs

I'm starting to use **EFS feature to encrypt several folders of my hard drive**, using *Right click > Properties > Advanced > Encrypt contents to secure data* (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIgEO.jpg)).

At the end of the process, a wizard suggests that I should save a copy of certificate on a safe place:

[image]

But I don't want to rely on a file certificate stored on 1, 2 or even 10 different places, that seems complex. And can lead to catastrophes [requiring black magic to recover the files](https://superuser.com/a/293740/221041). I would prefer to remember a password (even if it's a long password).

**Question: Let's say folder `C:\Test` is EFS-encrypted on computer A. If I move its hard drive to computer B** (example: computer A failure!), **how to recover the folder `C:\Test` , with just a password (and no other complex method like certificates, etc.)?**

In other words: can we avoid complex certificates methods (involving certificate files), and use a good (strong) password instead for EFS encryption/decryption?

Comment: A few other answers showing using the certificate to recover EFS-encrypted files on another computer can be tricky: https://superuser.com/questions/942149/how-to-use-backup-efs-certificate-to-decrypt-encrypted-files?rq=1, https://superuser.com/questions/649096/recover-efs-certificate-from-dead-motherboard?rq=1

Comment: And another one: https://superuser.com/questions/375142/efs-disallows-me-from-decrypting-files-on-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: Import the certificate used to encrypt the files on the other computer.  If you don't want to do that, then don't use EFS, because that's what's required

Comment: Can you import/export from another machine or OS, or can that only be done from the OS where the certificate was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent in this question:

> If I move its hard drive to computer B (example: computer A failure!), how to recover the folder C:\Test , with just a password (and no other complex method like certificates, etc.)?

It's impossible. EFS works with certificates, and not just "a password".

We have to backup the `.pfx` certificate file, and to import it on computer B, before being able to decrypt the files on computer B.

If one day we want to remove the certificate on computer B, [here is the solution](https://superuser.com/a/1263036/221041).

Comment: I mean, you could convert the .pfx file to hex, and then you have a 'password' to possibly remember. :P

Comment: @matterny that's what I did: I base64d the pfx file and printed it (will be stored by my grandma) ;)